# Searching for a sentence that I only know part of it using Google's operators

Tags: google-search, regex

I am looking for a particular combination of google hacking commands to find a sentence. 
For example, I am looking for ”where eagles dare”
In this case, I don’t have part of a sentence like the following example:

> where xxx dare

I am sure about the first and last word but I don’t know what is in the middle.
I used

```
“where” and “dare”
```

But it did not work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a wildcard operator when you don't remember a particular word. The asterisk (`*`) is used as a placeholder for any word(s) that you don't know in a particular phrase. Therefore it would be:

```
"where" * "dare"
```

or try:

```
"where * dare"
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: is "space" important ? does it count?

Comment: depends.... it works even without spaces but it can give you different results as with spaces...

Comment: There is a problem with result in the beginning , when i use “where” * “dare” it Shows somthing like (else where eagles dare) i want it exactly begin with “where” not something before it.